# How to extend/modify behaviour of vector type structs in Unity to achieve position wrapping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

I'm creating a grid based game using `Vector2Ints` to represent positions on the grid. The world needs to be wrapped on the x and y axes, meaning that if the world is 100x100 cells big then for an entity with `position = new Vector2Int(99, 99)` and `displacement = new Vector2Int(1,1)`, we'd have `newPosition = position + displacement` equal to `Vector2Int(0, 0)`. The obvious way initially seemed to somehow override the set method behaviour of the `Vector2Int` struct in Unity because then I can continue to benefit from all the other methods on the struct like addition, multiplication with ints etc. while still getting the "wrapping" functionality with every operation. This is key so I don't have to remember to keep calling a helper function.

The way I thought about achieving this would be to somehow extend the `Vector2Int` so I can set a `mapWidth` and `mapHeight`, and modify the `set` methods to `x = xIn % mapWidth` and `y = yIn % mapHeight`.

I would appreciate suggestions on how best to achieve the above without just duplicating the code, albeit with the minor modifications, of the whole Vector2Int struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extension method to any class like so:

```
// the class name here doesn't matter. Just some static class.
public static class Helpers
{
    public static Vector2Int Wrapped(this Vector2Int v, int wrapX, int wrapY)
    {
        return new Vector2Int(v.x % wrapX, v.y % wrapY);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Vector2Int vec = new Vector2Int(15,15);
Vector2Int vecWrapped = vec.Wrapped(10, 10);
```

vecWrapped will now be 5, 5.

It's the "this Vector2Int" in the method parameters that makes it extend the class.

EDIT:
On the question of whether it's possible to override the Set method, not directly no afaik. You can add an extension method called Set, but it can't have the same signature, ie. it can't be Set(x, y). You could add a method called something else though.

And afaik, there's no way to make it automatically 'gridify' after any operation on the vector.

As suggested by aybe, using "this ref" can make this much more usable though, removing the need to assign the return value.

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static int gridX = 10;
    public static int gridY = 10;

    public static void SetGrid(this ref Vector2Int v, int x, int y)
    {
        v.Set(x % gridX, y % gridY);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Vector2Int v = Vector2Int.zero;
v.SetGrid(15, 15);
```

v will now be 5, 5.

Comment: If supported by Unity, `this ref` would make it even easier to use.

Comment: Thanks Cadmonkey, but if I added a vector from vecWrapped to itself, this wouldn't reapply the wrapping operation right? I'd have to apply that every time I did an operation on a vector. One of the reasons I discussed overriding the set method on this new class was so that I don't have to remember to wrap each new vector to ensure it's pointing at a valid grid position, so I'm not sure this does what I need. I'll update the question

Comment: @aybe, pls could you provide a bit more detail, understand this and ref keywords but not in combination in this context, given that vector2Int is a struct and is passed by value

Comment: @Jinglesting Hi, I've added a bit of extra info. You can simplify things, but I don't think you can get exactly what you want. You can't derive from Vector2Int because it's a sealed class, so even with a custom class, you'd have to convert constantly to pass Vectors to other Unity methods.

Comment: @Jinglesting You can see the source code for Vector2Int here: [link](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2Int.cs)
You could make a wrapper class I guess.

Comment: ref will update the vector directly, bypassing the fact that defensive copies are made for structs, you won't have to assign the result back as you would usually have to do.